# Detectar si en la Base de datos hay un nuevo post

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pdo

en mi home.php tengo esto

```
<div id="content"></div>
<img src="img/loading.gif" id="loading" alt="loading" style="display:none;" />
```

y en mi post-data.php

```
<style>
a{
  color: #ffff;
}
a:hovera{
  color: #ffff;
}
</style>
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=;charset=utf8mb4',"","");
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM post LIMIT 1");
$sql->execute();
while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $_SESSION['avatar'] = $result['avatar'];

  echo '<li class="rv b agz">
         <div class="rw"><p>Nuevas Publicaciones!</p></div>
        </li>';
}
?>
```

ahora quiero que cuando detecte que en mi base de datos se añadieron nuevas publicaciones y en el Home.php aparea el mensaje de que hay nuevos post y que al pinchar en el `<li>` carge todos los post nuevos en Descendente sin que afecte a los que se cargaron antes 
yo antes para mostrar usaba este codigo

```
(function($)
{
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $.ajaxSetup(
      {
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function() {
              $('#content').hide();
              $('#loading').show();
          },
          complete: function() {
              $('#loading').hide();
              $('#content').show();
          },
          success: function() {
              $('#loading').hide();
              $('#content').show();
          }
      });
      var $container = $("#content");
     $container.load("post-data.php");
      var refreshId = setInterval(function()
      {
        $container.load('post-data.php');
      }, 70000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

mi meta es crear un sistema de actualización como lo tiene twitter que carga los post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una variable para almacenar la cantidad de registros.

Y cuando hagas el **setInterval** vuelve a contar los registros.

Entonces compara la cantidad antigua con el conteo nuevo, si hay diferencia que refresque el listado.

Voy a poner un ejemplo:

```
    var n_old_post = 0;
$.ajax({
                    url: "contar_post.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true,
                          success: function(result) {
                            n_old_post = result

                          }
                  });



   var refreshId = setInterval(function()
          {
            $.ajax({
                    url: "hay_nuevos.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true,
                    data: {
                      n_old_post : n_old_post} ,
                          success: function(result) {
                            if (result) {
                            // Cambias un div o bien recargas la list
                            // n_old_post es el valor antiguo.
                            // Por ejemplo:
                            $('#div-con-los-li').html(result)
                          }
                  });

          }, 70000);
```

**contar_post** cuenta los registros y devuelve un número.

Luego en **hay_nuevos.php** ha de contra y comparar con la variable **n_old_post** y devolver true o false, o bien traes la lista con los últimos post.

Ejemplo de **contar_post.php**

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=;charset=utf8mb4',"","");
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) as cuantos FROM post");
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result['cuantos']

?>
```

Ejemplo de **hay_nuevos.php**

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=;charset=utf8mb4',"","");
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
$sql->execute();
while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $_SESSION['avatar'] = $result['avatar'];

  echo '<li class="rv b agz">
         <div class="rw"><p>Nuevas Publicaciones!</p></div>
        </li>';
}
?>
```

*Es a modo de ejemplo, no lo he testado y pueden haber errores de sintaxis. Pero esa es la idea.*

Comment: Y el código en los dos PHP como seria? Seria el mismo como lo nuestro arriba?

Comment: Sí, el archivo **hay_nuevos.php** tendría la parte que pusiste arriba con `SELECT` y el `echo` con el resultado. O lo que necesites, pero sí funcionaria como un pHP cualquiera y lo muestras en un div con js. (Ahora modifico la respuesta)